# Using array to find HCF, getting unknown output (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So no matter what I input, I get the result 176 when for my last output.
My logic is that I can make an Array(comfactors) and placing common factors in it. After that, I take the highest number and place it in comfactors[0] and output it.
If anyone else has any other recommendation to do it, do tell. Always looking to learn.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef int integer;
void generate_factors(integer factor1[], int a, integer factor2[], int b);
void findHCF(int[], int[], int, int);
int main()
{
int x, y;

cout << "Enter first integer: " << endl;
cin >> x;

cout << "Enter second integer: " << endl;
cin >> y;



integer *integerArray1 = new integer[x], *integerArray2 = new integer[y];

generate_factors(integerArray1, x, integerArray2, y);
findHCF(integerArray1, integerArray2, x, y);

return 0;
}

void generate_factors(integer factor1[], int a, integer factor2[], int b)
{
int i, j;
cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "Factors of " << a << " are: " << endl;
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{
    if ((a%i) == 0)
    {
        factor1[i - 1] = i;
        cout << factor1[i - 1] << " ";
    }

}

cout << "\n" << endl;

cout << "Factors of " << b << " are: " << endl;
for (j = 1; j <= b; j++)
{
    if ((b%j) == 0)
    {
        factor2[j - 1] = j;
        cout << factor2[j - 1] << " ";
    }

}


}

void findHCF(integer Array1[], integer Array2[], int a, int b)
{
int i, j, k;
int comfactors[1024];

for (i = 0; i <= a; i++) 
{
    for(j = 0; j <= b; j++)
    {

        if (Array1[j] == Array2[i]) 
        {
            comfactors[i] = i;
        }

    }

}


for (k = 0;k < a+b; ++k)
{
    if (comfactors[0] < comfactors[k])
    {
    comfactors[0] = comfactors[k];}
}
cout << "\n\nThe Highest Common Factor is " << comfactors[0];
}
```

Comment: `integerArray1` is uninitialized. `generate_factors` assigns some of its elements, but not all; the rest contain random garbage. Same with `integerArray2`, of course. But `findHCF` looks at all elements, initialized and uninitialized alike. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: In addition, `findHCF` mixes up which bound goes with which array, so it likely performs a buffer overrun, too.

Comment: intergerArray1 is initialized after getting the inputs from the user

Comment: The pointer itself is initialized, by making it point to an initialized block of memory. The contents of that block are then initialized in spots, but most of it remains garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong answer because here your arrays are filled with garbade values at random spots ,
 for example in your function `generate_factors` only those spots are filled for which the condition is being satisfied. So because of that when you search common values in function`findHCF` those garbage value comes and cause unexpected output to occur.
So you should initialize the arrays with 1

Although a simple way to calculate the HCF of two numbers is the use of `Euclid's Algorithm`.

Here's an implementation of Euclid's algorithm in C++:

```
int hcf(int a, int b) {
   if (b == 0) {
      return a;
   } else {
      return hcf(b, a % b);
   }
}
```